# Create a the missing x64 solution platform in VS project

Tags: c++, windows, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I have a c++ shell extension VS 2008 project that I want to migrate from Win32 to x64 bits since I have switched to a windows 7 x64 version.

I go to **Configuration manager**, I click **Active solution platform**, then **New** and i get the **New Solution Platform** window with the followings:

[image]

and

[image]

In [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx) tutorial it says that that I Should do:

- In the **Active Solution Platform** *drop-down list*, select the  option to open the **New Solution Platform dialog box**. (Which I have)
- In the Type or select the new platform drop-down list, select a 64-bit platform. (Which I don't have).

Q1. How do I cope with this?
Q2. What is the relation between *Solution Platform* and *Project Platform* ?

Comment: did you install the x64 platform compilers when you installed the IDE?

Comment: The x64 compiler is not installed by default in 2005/2008. What edition are you using? x64 compiler is not available for Visual Studio Express.

Comment: Yes, you guys nailed it , I did not have the x64 compiler.. installing now, waiting to see if it is all good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target x64 targets with VS2008 you must install the x64 compilers, they are not installed by default. Other options would be using VS2010 or newer.